# What makes a building classify as a house for villagers in 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was building a village and wondered why villagers interacted with certain building but not others, e.g. they entered the library I built by not the church. I have been told that a bed and a door makes the building a house but I’m starting to question my knowledge of this. Please help.

Comment: This question should stay open, because iron golem spawning changed a lot in 1.14.

Comment: Your answer is that there is no house detection anymore, but villagers are responsible for spawning golems. The exact circumstances are still being looked into by the technical Minecraft community.

Comment: @FabianRöling Heads up, I have added a bounty to the former question to get an updated answer for it :)